# C# deserializing array always returns null for the element

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, xml, serialization

I've got a problem when deserializing partially works. When I have an xml node with attributes, all the attribute values get loaded correctly into my class but when I use elements, it just returns null.

I have the following stored in an xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1"?>
...
<numbers>
    <number id="55">name1</number>
    <number id="4">name2</number>
</numbers>
...
```

Class is defined as follows:

```
public class root
{

    [XmlArray("numbers")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "number")]
    public List<NumberObj> numbers { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class NumberObj
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }    
}
```

What keeps being null is the name.. I've tried multiple things as changing the list to arrary but whatever I do name is null.

I see the above class is wrong because when I serialize it back to XML i get the following:

```
<numbers>
    <number id="123">
        <number>abc</number>
    </number>
    <number id="45">
        <number>abc</number>
    </number>
</numbers>
```

Could anyone point my in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add the snippet, where you parse the xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think thaht the correct class definition must be something like this

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="number")]
public class Number {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="numbers")]
public class Numbers {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="number")]
    public List<Number> Number { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Adding the XmlText solved it for me